# Recreating "split screen" + "slide" from iMovie in Final Cut

Tags: imovie, video-editing, final-cut-pro

So there's a super simple effect you can do in iMovie, where you add an image on top of the timeline, then set it to **Split Screen**, and use the **Slide** slider to set the timing, and the image will automatically slide in from the side, displace the main video so it is now centered in the remaining space, then slide back out after.

I LOVE this effect. It's a great way to have things on screen and it's a huge time-saver that the main video automatically animates to maintain a decent layout.

Here's how it looks on an iMovie timeline:

[image: screenshot of the configuration described above]

**So the question is, what's the easiest way to get this same effect in Final Cut?**

I know how to add the image on top, and how to slide the image below over to align it, but it's a lot of clicking each time, and I haven't even integrated the "slide" animation. I'd love a drag-and-drop solution that gives a similar effect so I can use it over and over. Maybe it's already built-in?